# Erro 1064 no MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

Escrevi o seguinte código para a aula de Banco de Dados da faculdade:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE estoque;
USE estoque;

CREATE TABLE produtos( /*o erro ocorre aqui nesse parêntese*/
    INT codP,
    CHAR (20) nomeP,
    FLOAT precoP,
    PRIMARY KEY (codP)
    FOREIGN KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE fornecedores( /*e nesse parêntese*/
    INT id,
    CHAR (40) nomeF,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (codP)
);
```

Todavia, ocorrem erros de sintaxe onde comentei. E mesmo pesquisando manuais em sites ou na própria documentação, estão escritos da mesma maneira que eu escrevi, então não sei como corrigir e nem tem como dar procedência nessa código.

Comment: Reveja suas cláusulas FOREIGN KEY. Qual campo está referenciando qual campo em qual tabela?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Inverta a variável e seu formato assim
2 - A referencia externa precisa definir ao que ela se conecta na tabela e não pode ser criada a uma tabela que ainda não foi criada. terá que defini-la depois de criar a segunda tabela.

```
CREATE DATABASE estoque;
USE estoque;

CREATE TABLE produtos(
  codP INT,
  nomeP CHAR (20),
  precoP FLOAT,
  PRIMARY KEY (codP)
);
CREATE TABLE fornecedores( /*e nesse parêntese*/
  id INT,
  nomeF CHAR (40) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) reference produtos(codP)
);
ALTER TABLE produtos
ADD FOREIGN KEY (codP) REFERENCES fornecedores(id);
```

Comment: Não sei o que se pretende implantar com esta definição de tabelas mas se, por acaso, for um relacionamento N:N, que seria o normal, esta implantação não vai funcionar. Funciona para o caso de um relacionamento 1:1, um fornecedor fornece um único produto e um produto é fornecido por um único fornecedor e, neste caso, não há motivos para dividir em duas tabelas.

Comment: só fiz o que ele pediu, mas de acordo.